# Silverlight 4 - 401.2 response with Windows Auth

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, iis, authentication

I have a custom SL4 app, that fails in a Test Environment.  The app is configured with Windows Auth, and the App Pool is a Domain (service) Account.

This worked as configured and then something environmental change and now the site doesnt consume the Windows Credentials automatically through IIS8.  I get prompted (401.1) for creds.  After 3 failures I get a 401.2.  I am not sure if this is Kerberos related.  or if its in my web.config.

Anyone have any ideas??

Comment: I was able to circumvent my problem by deploying to a new server.  The issue manifested a few months after successfully deployment, supposedly related to a security configuration for a different app (same server).  I kept the old environment and will report back if I uncover the cause

Comment: You should post the answer and accept it yourself or delete the question so it won't show up in the Unanswered list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question here:

This article got me going in the right direction

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907273

Essentially this was a failure in configuration between my IIS, the Authentication settings and the Bindings on my RIA Service.  I removed any Binding Configuration I had in the config file for the RIA service and then I made sure that only one auth type was configured in IIS.